# Automatically activate mic button (Voice input mode ) from UITextField when I Press other button

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to convert voice to text & I am using built in mic phone button from the keyboard its work perfectly to convert voice to text But Client requirement is to add external mic button & handle keyboard mic button event. So how to open voice input mode when I press external mic button from the screen. 
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You cannot make use of the keyboard speech recognition externally without keyboard speech button. If you want your app to recognize speech externally without keyboard then you have to make use any third party speech recognition SDK. Do google for speech recognizers for ios.

Also i would give a hint that in iOS10 apple introduced a Speech recognition library called SFSpeechRecognizer. If you are planning for future you can give it a try.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I will wait for iOS10 Its not immediate need.